# How to get MessageResource or ApplicationContext object in RestController using Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to get messages from properties files. When I create ApplicationContext object using XML, then I am able to retrieve all messages from properties files. For the same messages in controller class, I used @Autowired annotation for MessageResource or ApplicationContext object, but it gives different instance (handle).

Can you please help me here to get same instance of ApplicationContext or MessageResource in RestController?

config.xml

```
<bean name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages/greeting"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

messages/greeting.properties

```
message.greeting=Hello, World!
```

Application Class with main method

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.util.Locale;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:config.xml");
        System.out.println(context.getApplicationName());
        String greeting = context.getMessage("message.greeting", null,Locale.ROOT);
        System.out.println("message.greeting = " + greeting);
        // output: message.greeting = Hello, World!
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

REST controller:

```
package com.example.demo.greeting;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Locale;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @GetMapping
    public String get() {
        System.out.println("Using context: "+ context.getMessage("message.greeting", null, "default", Locale.ROOT)); 
        // output: Using context: default
        System.out.println("Using messageSource: "+ messageSource.getMessage("message.greeting", null, "default", Locale.ROOT)); 
        // output: Using messageSource: default
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

I have also tried following code. It creates a bean in config class and then we can use MessageSource using @Autowired annotation. But, I want to avoid hard-coded file path in code and manual bean creation.

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages/greeting"); // hard-coded file path
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: I am using Spring-Boot 2 RC1, Spring WebFlux, and Java 9.

Comment: And how is it not hard-coded in the xml, which is packaged in the same application? Also you should be working with the framework not around the framework. Spring Boot automatically loads messages and registers a `MessageSource. Place a `messages.properties` (not `greeting.properties`) in `src/main/resources` and Spring Boot will load it for you and you can use `MessageSource`.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum . It works. I agree, xml is also hard-coded, but I think, this is the best place where I can configure required settings. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is XML or Java. They are both for providing configuration and neither is more or less hardcoded as the other (especially with the support in Spring Boot for externalizing configuration).